# Add fourth column to table

Tags: tables

I know that this question has been asked before, but I am having troubling solving the issue in my case. I have a table and I simply want to add a third column to show the regression output from my third equation. I looked at "defining multiple columns" in the LaTeX wikibook, but I didn't have much luck extrapolating from there. Can you help?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\usepackage{amsmath,geometry,siunitx,booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
%\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\usepackage{amsmath,geometry,siunitx,booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C@{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\sisetup{group-separator={,}, group-minimum-digits=4}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small, labelfont=bf, singlelinecheck=no}


\usepackage{%booktabs, 
            makecell, %tabularx
            }
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed} 
\restylefloat{figure}

\title{\LARGE \bf ECON 425 Term Paper}

\author{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}[!htb]
\caption{Estimates of pay-performance sensitivity.}
\label{tab:table1}
OLS regressions of CEO salary and CEO total compensation on change in shareholder wealth. Standard errors in parentheses.

    \medskip
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \small
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}L ll@{}}
    \toprule
\thead[l]{Dependent\\ variable}
            &  \thead[l]{CEO\\
                         salary\\
                         (eq. \ref{eqn:first})}
                                    & \thead[l]{CEO total\\
                                            compensation\\
                                            (eq. \ref{eqn:second})} \\


    \midrule
Return       &  -0.320 (0.083)        & 2.213 (1.545)                    \\
Logbonus
                & -5.269 (1.38)   & ---          \\
    \addlinespace
Return*Volume   & 0.00 (0.000)       & ---                        \\
Stock Awards    & $0.036^*$ (0.000)    & ---                    \\
Option Awards    & 0.023 (0.000)        & ---                         \\
Other Compensation & 0.028 (0.00) & ---
    \\
Age & 33.387 (4.567) & 913.016 (84.768)
    \\
agesq & -0.217 (0.039) & -7.435 (0.733)
    \\
male & -2.601 (18.079) & -465.612 (337.631)
    \\
outdoors & -173.761 (77.902) & -4268.128 (1453.675) 
    \\
mining & -178.289 (26.792) & -972.327 (499.369)
    \\
utilities & -199.853 (34.906) & -4217.222 (651.127)
    \\
construction & -102.424 (33.259 & -3572.244 (620.558)
    \\
wholesale & -193.954 (28.814) & -3827.542 (537.382)
    \\
information & -218.414 (24.494) & -618.642 (456.968)
    \\
finance & -160.005 (23.320) & -3078.595 (434.591)
    \\
realestate & -303.096 (25.248) & -3410.482 (470.966)  
    \\
professional & -238.323 (27.486) & -3776.246 (512.813)
    \\
waste  & -186.965 (31.766) & -3365.898 (592.813)
    \\
education & -287.113 (50.956) & -5770.548 (950.712)
    \\
healthcare & -153.385 (32.953) & -2123.471 (615.121) 
    \\
arts & 178.082 (56.622) & -2303.748 (1056.786)
    \\
food & -34.24 (31.091) & -2656.446 (579.849)
    \\
other & -109.691 (61.642) & -3786.196 (1150.511)
    \\
manufacturing & -193.729 (22.394) & -2540.859 (417.698)
    \\
transportation & -313.349 (29.509) & -3678.069 (551.778)
    \\
retail &  $\underset{(25.756)}{-80.145}$ & -2295.232 (480.656)
    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\smallskip
$^{*}$ Significant at the 1\% level.
    \end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Here's how it currently looks:

[image]

Thanks as always!

FOLLOW-UP @SAMCARTER

How can I fix this issue with the 4th column? I'd like it to look like the others.

[image]

Comment: You already have three columns. What is your expected result?

Comment: TeXnician--Ah, I suppose I do. I would like a "4th" column, then, to the right of "CEO total compensation (eq. 2)" that will be "TITLE (eq. 3)"

Comment: You should have a look at the siunitx package. It allows to easily align the numbers in your table and also to unify the usage of minus signs and hyphens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an additional column with your desired alignment, for example `l` in `@{}L lll@{}` and add an additional number at the end of each row.

Off-topic:

- Please don't use deprecated font commands such as `\bf`.
- please do not load the same package multiple times

---

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,geometry,siunitx,booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small, labelfont=bf, singlelinecheck=no}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed} 
\restylefloat{figure}

\title{\LARGE \textbf{ECON 425 Term Paper}}

\author{}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!htb]
    \caption{Estimates of pay-performance sensitivity.}
    \label{tab:table1}
    OLS regressions of CEO salary and CEO total compensation on change in shareholder wealth. Standard errors in parentheses.

    \medskip
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \small
    \makegapedcells
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}L lll@{}}
        \toprule
        \thead[l]{Dependent\\ variable} &  \thead[l]{CEO\\ salary\\ (eq. \ref{eqn:first})} & \thead[l]{CEO total\\ compensation\\ (eq. \ref{eqn:second})} & 4th column \\
        \midrule
        Return &  \num{-0.320} (\num{0.083}) & \num{2.213} (\num{1.545}) & \num{42}\\
        Logbonus & \num{-5.269} (\num{1.38}) & {---} & \num{42}\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}

    \smallskip
    $^{*}$ Significant at the 1\% level.
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @texmex You already loaded it in your origional code, but you don't use it. Have a look at the package documentation http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf how to align columns using the `S` column type.

Comment: Gotcha. I also have a follow-up question if you would please see the original post

Comment: @texmex Edits are not the best place to ask new questions. Also when you ask a new questions, please specify what you mean with `issue`. BTW @ pings in yoru questions don't work. you can only ping people in comments if they either already commented to the specific question or answer or (like here) if they are the original author of the question or answer.

Comment: @texmex for using siunitx see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430290/36296

Comment: (the @ ping still isnt working) okay, I will ask a new question. Thanks!

Comment: Sam carter, I actually can't post more than 6 questions within a 24-hour period. I would really appreciate it if you took a look at the issue within this thread

Comment: @texmex Then please state what the issue with the fourth column is!

Comment: In the picture I added, look under "Dependent Variable" that part-- "(not controlling for industry" should be part of the title of the 4th column. It would also be nice to add in the equation reference to equation no. 3 but haven't had any luck with that either.

Comment: I added the question to the main page @samcarter